# Replacing the x509 SSL certificate on an IIS hosted WCF server and client apps

Tags: .net, wcf, iis

TL;DR - WCF app on IIS, Server Component, and Workstation Client Component are all looking for a certificate with a thumbprint that is expired, and subsequently untrusted.  Can't figure out where to disable certificate validation.

Long Details:

I've read dozens of articles about implementing SSL with WCF, but I can't find any that talk about replacing the SSL certificate that a WCF server and client app use to validate communication.

The predicament that I'm in is I'm working with a piece of software that went out of business a year ago and our customer information is locked inside of the old app.  We've since moved on to a new vendor for our records management about two years ago, but we go back to the old system to reference information from time to time, so the system just sits there in a read-only type of role.

The record management system is comprised of ...
- Back end SQL server
- Front end IIS server and application services.  The IIS server has multiple application pools running in .NET 4 mode.  The application services are all Windows Services that start automatically when the front end server starts up.

This system used to be internet facing, it is not anymore, I've cut all access to it from the outside world off, you have to be on the same LAN or the console of the front end server to use the client app.  Since this used to be internet facing, it was secured with an SSL certificate from a major CA and was in good standing, until about two weeks ago when the SSL certificate expired.  Now I'm getting the following error when I try to launch the client app ... "Token validation failure. The X.509 certificate CN=fqdn_of_frontend_server, OU=CA_that_issued chain building failed. The certificate that was used has a trust chain that cannot be verified. Replace the certificate or change the certificateValidationMode. A required certificate is not within its validity period when verifying against the current system clock or the timestamp in the signed file."

Before you say ... "Why not just rollback the system clock on the app and the DB servers to a time when the cert was valid?" ... because I don't want to have to intervene anytime one of the 50 people who have the client app on their machine want to use it.  Inevitably, the date will continue to creep past expired SSL date and we're kind of in a regulated industry, so if auditors asked for access logs to the old system and the dates were not the correct dates, I'd be searching for a new job.

I bought a new, trusted CA SSL certificate and installed it into IIS and bound it to the default website (the only site) where the IIS Application Pools are running.  That did not work, the client app is still looking for the thumbprint of the old SSL certificate.

So there's three sides to this whole thing?  Front end server running IIS application pools and Windows services, and the last side is the client app.

From the Front End Server Windows service server.exe.config file ...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Mfg.Industry.BasicHttpBinding.Configuration.Open" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ConfigurationServiceUrl" value="http://fqdn_of_frontend_server/Name_of.ConfigurationService" />
    <add key="ConfigurationServiceEncryptionKey" value="some_96_character_long_scrambled_key" />
    <add key="ApplicationName" value="App Server" />
    <add key="LocalHostName" value="fqdn_of_frontend_server" />
    <add key="RedirectToLocalHost" value="False" />
    <add key="WCF_STSConnection_Binding_Type" value="BasicHttpBinding" />
    <add key="WCF_STSConnection_Binding_Configuration_Name" value="Mfg.Industry.BasicHttpBinding.Configuration.Open" />
    <add key="WCF_InteractionProcessingConnection_Binding_Type" value="BasicHttpBinding" />
    <add key="WCF_InteractionProcessingConnection_Binding_Configuration_Name" value="Mfg.Industry.BasicHttpBinding.Configuration.Open" />
    <add key="FilterCheckPeriod" value="60" />
    <add key="ACEVerificationPeriod" value="5" />
    <add key="TestReachingQueueWaitingTime" value="500" />
    <add key="ApplicationIdleTimeout" value="300" />
    <add key="TestMessageSize" value="30" />
    <add key="PRCServiceCalculationWaitingTime" value="1" />
    <add key="PRCVerificationPeriod" value="1" />
    <add key="CommunityWebsiteUrl" value="https://some_link_now_defunct_to_Mfg/Contact-Support/" />
    <add key="ACTGVerificationPeriod" value="5" />
    <add key="ACTG_AR_VerificationPeriod" value="5" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

From the Front End Server IIS Application Pool web.config file ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="ConfigurationService.Encryption" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings configSource="AppSettings.config">
  </appSettings>
  <ConfigurationService.Encryption configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">
    <EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
      <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
      <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
          <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
          <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <KeyName>Rsa Key</KeyName>
          </KeyInfo>
          <CipherData>
            <CipherValue>some_172_character_key</CipherValue>
          </CipherData>
        </EncryptedKey>
      </KeyInfo>
      <CipherData>
        <CipherValue>some_460_character_key</CipherValue>
      </CipherData>
    </EncryptedData>
  </ConfigurationService.Encryption>
  <system.web>
    <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="20" slidingExpiration="true" />
    </authentication>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20" />
    <!--<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error"/>-->
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="RoleManager" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    omitted
  </runtime>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAuthentication" />
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICertificateValidator" />
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAuthorization" />
        <binding name="SecurityFrameworkSoap" />
        <binding name="SecurityAdministrationSoap" />
        <binding name="SecurityPolicySoap" />
        <binding name="SecuritySynchronizationSoap" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAuthentication" contract="StsAuthentication.IAuthentication" name="BasicHttpBinding_IAuthentication" />
      <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAuthorization" contract="STSAuthorization.IAuthorization" name="BasicHttpBinding_IAuthorization" />
      <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICertificateValidator" contract="STSCertVldtr.ICertificateValidator" name="BasicHttpBinding_ICertificateValidator" />
      <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecurityAdministrationSoap" contract="SecAdmin.SecurityAdministrationSoap" name="SecurityAdministrationSoap" />
      <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecurityPolicySoap" contract="SecPolicy.SecurityPolicySoap" name="SecurityPolicySoap" />
      <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecuritySynchronizationSoap" contract="SecSync.SecuritySynchronizationSoap" name="SecuritySynchronizationSoap" />
      <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecurityFrameworkSoap" contract="SF.SecurityFrameworkSoap" name="SecurityFrameworkSoap" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

From the Client Application appname.exe.config file ...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="exceptionHandling" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Configuration.ExceptionHandlingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0ccaa1d06491a513" />
    <section name="securityCryptographyConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security.Cryptography.Configuration.CryptographySettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security.Cryptography, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0ccaa1d06491a513" />
    <section name="informationMonitoringSynchronization" type="System.Configuration.NameValueFileSectionHandler" />
    <section name="assembliesToJIT" type="System.Configuration.NameValueFileSectionHandler" />
    <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0ccaa1d06491a513" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WCF_Base_URL" value="net.tcp://localhost:{0}/Allscripts.Homecare/Services/{1}/{2}" />
    <add key="WCF_Hosting_Binding_Configuration_Name" value="Mfg.Industry.NetTcpBinding.Configuration.Open" />
    <add key="WCF_Hosting_Binding_Type" value="NetTcpBinding" />
    <add key="SLPingTimeout" value="2" />
    <add key="WCF_Hosting_Start_Port" value="2222" />
    <add key="WCF_Hosting_End_Port" value="9199" />
  </appSettings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="bin" />
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <exceptionHandling>
    <exceptionPolicies>
      <add name="Authentication Exception Policy">
        <exceptionTypes>
          <add name="AuthenticationException" type="Mfg.Industry.Security.Framework.Facade.AuthenticationException, Mfg.Industry.Security.Framework.Facade, Version=17.2.0.163, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5afe0c9031f3768" postHandlingAction="NotifyRethrow">
            <exceptionHandlers />
          </add>
          <add name="Exception" type="System.Exception, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" postHandlingAction="NotifyRethrow">
            <exceptionHandlers />
          </add>
        </exceptionTypes>
      </add>
      <add name="Unhandled Exception Policy">
        <exceptionTypes>
          <add name="Exception" type="System.Exception, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" postHandlingAction="NotifyRethrow">
            <exceptionHandlers>
            </exceptionHandlers>
          </add>
          <add name="IndustryException" type="Mfg.Industry.IndustryException, Mfg.Industry.Lib, Version=17.2.0.163, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5afe0c9031f3768" postHandlingAction="NotifyRethrow">
            <exceptionHandlers>
            </exceptionHandlers>
          </add>
        </exceptionTypes>
      </add>
      <add name="User Services Exception Policy">
        <exceptionTypes>
          <add name="Exception" type="System.Exception, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" postHandlingAction="None">
            <exceptionHandlers>
            </exceptionHandlers>
          </add>
        </exceptionTypes>
      </add>
    </exceptionPolicies>
  </exceptionHandling>
  <securityCryptographyConfiguration>
    <hashProviders>
      <add algorithmType="System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" saltEnabled="false" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithmProvider, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security.Cryptography, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" name="MD5CryptoServiceProvider" />
    </hashProviders>
  </securityCryptographyConfiguration>
  <informationMonitoringSynchronization>
    <add key="BatchSize" value="15" />
    <add key="CompressionEnabled" value="True" />
    <add key="MultithreadingEnabled" value="False" />
  </informationMonitoringSynchronization>
  <system.net>
    <settings>
      <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" />
    </settings>
  </system.net>
  <assembliesToJIT>
    <add key="MfgIndustrySecurityCommon" value="Mfg.Industry.Security.Common" />
    <add key="MfgIndustrySecurityFramework" value="Mfg.Industry.Security.Framework" />
    <add key="MfgIndustrySecurityWebServicesClient" value="Mfg.Industry.Security.WebServices.Client" />
    <add key="MfgIndustrySecurityFrameworkFacade" value="Mfg.Industry.Security.Framework.Facade" />
    <add key="MfgIndustrySecurityAdministrationCommon" value="Mfg.Industry.Security.Administration.Common" />
    <add key="MfgIndustrySynchronization" value="Mfg.Industry.Synchronization" />
    <add key="MfgIndustrySynchronizationData" value="Mfg.Industry.Synchronization.Data" />
    <add key="MfgIndustryDFAClient" value="Mfg.Industry.DFA.Client" />
    <add key="MfgIndustryDFAFramework" value="Mfg.Industry.DFA.Framework" />
    <add key="EligibilityWebClient" value="Mfg.Industry.Eligibility.WebClient" />
    <add key="InformationMonitoring" value="Mfg.Industry.InformationMonitoring" />
    <add key="EligibilityClient" value="Mfg.Industry.Eligibility.Client" />
    <add key="SplitBillingRule" value="Mfg.Industry.SplitBillingRule" />
    <add key="EventManagerClient" value="Mfg.Industry.EventManager.Client" />
    <add key="MfgIndustrySanctionImportClient" value="Mfg.Industry.SanctionImport.Client" />
    <add key="MfgIndustryTestInterfaces" value="Mfg.Industry.TestInterfaces" />
    <add key="MfgIndustryOpenAPIClient" value="Mfg.Industry.OpenAPI.Client" />
    <add key="MfgIndustryCommonDefinitionData" value="Mfg.Industry.Common.DefinitionData" />
    <add key="InfomaticsMisc" value="Infomatics2.Win.Misc.v6.1, Version=6.1.20061.28, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb" />
    <add key="InfomaticsGrid" value="Infomatics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v6.1, Version=6.1.20061.28, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb" />
    <add key="InfomaticsEditors" value="Infomatics2.Win.UltraWinEditors.v6.1, Version=6.1.20061.28, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb" />
    <add key="InfomaticsFolio" value="Infomatics2.Win.UltraWinFolio.v6.1, Version=6.1.20061.28, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb" />
    <add key="InfomaticsFolio63" value="Infomatics2.Win.UltraWinFolio.v6.3, Version=6.3.20063.1091, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb" />
    <add key="InfomaticsTab" value="Infomatics2.Win.UltraWinTabControl.v6.1, Version=6.1.20061.28, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb" />
    <add key="InfomaticsWin" value="Infomatics2.Win.v6.1, Version=6.1.20061.28, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb" />
    <add key="InfomaticsTree" value="Infomatics2.Win.UltraWinTree.v6.1, Version=6.1.20061.28, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb" />
    <add key="InfomaticsShared" value="Infomatics2.Shared.v6.1, Version=6.1.20061.28, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb" />
    <add key="DevExpressUtils" value="DevExpress.Utils, Version=2.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=79868b8147b5eae4" />
    <add key="DevExpressEditors" value="DevExpress.XtraEditors, Version=2.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=79868b8147b5eae4" />
    <add key="CommonControls" value="Mfg.Industry.Forms.Controls" />
    <add key="MfgIndustryDFAClientData" value="Mfg.Industry.DFA.Client.Data" />
    <add key="MfgIndustryDFAClientDataFacade" value="Mfg.Industry.DFA.Client.Data.Facade" />
    <add key="MfgIndustryDFAClientSharedInterfaces" value="Mfg.Industry.DFA.Client.SharedInterfaces" />
    <add key="InformationMonitoringData" value="Mfg.Industry.InformationMonitoring.Data" />
    <add key="Eligibility" value="Mfg.Industry.Eligibility" />
    <add key="EligibilityCommon" value="Mfg.Industry.Eligibility.Common" />
    <add key="OnboardAndStatusConfiguration" value="Mfg.Industry.EventManager.OnboardAndStatusConfiguration" />
    <add key="EventManagerClientCommon" value="Mfg.Industry.EventManager.Client.Common" />
    <add key="EventManagerCommon" value="Mfg.Industry.EventManager.Common" />
    <add key="MfgIndustryFormsControls" value="Mfg.Industry.Forms.Controls" />
    <add key="MfgIndustryHelpManagerHelpClient" value="Mfg.Industry.HelpManager.HelpClient" />
    <add key="MfgIndustryPayrollCommon" value="Mfg.Industry.Payroll.Common" />
    <add key="MfgIndustryReportCommon" value="Mfg.Industry.Report.Common" />
  </assembliesToJIT>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="Mfg.Industry.NetTcpBinding.Configuration.Open" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <loggingConfiguration name="Logging Application Block" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="General" logWarningsWhenNoCategoriesMatch="true">
    <listeners>
      <add listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.CustomTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0ccaa1d06491a513" traceOutputOptions="None" type="Mfg.Industry.Plugin.Diagnostics.DebugTraceListener, Mfg.Industry.Plugin.Diagnostics" name="DebugTraceListener" initializeData="" formatter="" />
    </listeners>
    <categorySources>
      <add switchValue="All" name="General" />
    </categorySources>
    <specialSources>
      <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events">
        <listeners>
          <add name="DebugTraceListener" />
        </listeners>
      </allEvents>
      <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category" />
      <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings" />
    </specialSources>
  </loggingConfiguration>
</configuration>
```

Which files do I need to edit to simply disable WCF certificate validation?  I've tried things like ...

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <settings>
      <servicePointManager checkCertificateName="false" checkCertificateRevocationList="false" />
    </settings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

And I keep running into road blocks.  Ultimately I would like to use the new SSL certificate that I bought, but that means I'm going to have to go through this process again someday, so I might as well just turn the certificate validation completely off.

Comment: You could still put this on the web, by setting up a frontend proxy with a valid certificate, as long as you can show the network path between the proxy and the web app is not susceptible to interception. If the proxy is installed on the same server, or in another server in the same secure LAN, that would probably be OK. I wonder whether you could then serve non-encrypted traffic from the app, and force everyone to go through the proxy. That would get rid of your cert problem completely, I think.

Comment: @halfer ... That's WAY over my head, I am but a humble IT guy.  What I've learned so far has been by luck!  That's why I'm coming to you gurus. Edit: this never needs to be web accessible ever again, just need to be able to access the app from our LAN.

Comment: Could you make a case to your boss to have a contractor come in and give you some advice for a day or two? If you are in a regulated industry, there surely should be some budget for it.

Comment: There are a number of [resources here about setting up a reverse HTTPS proxy server](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=microsoft+iis+proxy+reverse+https) in front of your application. However, if a wrong configuration could result in employment Armageddon, it might be worth having a go at it and then getting that contractor to come in anyway, to verify it is done correctly.

Comment: @halfer I was just hoping to figure out where to stop the certificate validation.  I can test all I want, back up the files I'm modifying before testing.  If it works, I'm golden.  If not, I swap the files back and restart the services.